# TeamCity checkout GitHub repo to specific absolute path

Tags: github, path, teamcity, git-checkout

My TeamCity VCS Root step needs to checkout a specific GitHub repo to a specific absolute folder on the agent ( Windows server ) :

```
c:\github\{organization}\{repo}
```

I'm not understanding how to construct my checkout rule to do this.

By default, checkout rules are relative to the checkout dir which is recommended to be left at the default value.

I only want one repo to check-out to the absolute path - the others are fine at relative locations.

Further complicating, I can't be sure the TC server or agent has a C drive.

Comment: Teamcity takes absolute as well as relative path as the checkout directory so I don't see any problems here. Can you clarify what exactly doesn't work when you specify absolute path?

Comment: What if C drive doesn't exist on agent ? ( I have no control over how agents are imaged )

Comment: The build will crash then and Teamcity will tell you why it crashed. Maybe you are looking for some default Teamcity path you want to rely on e.g. `agent.home.dir`. Can you provide more details about your case so that to give you a better advise?

Comment: It's not complicated. The agent just needs to model the deploy targets = the app web-servers. My app git clones its local repo at `c:\github\{organization}\{repo}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Teamcity can work with both absolute and relative path. If you know exactly what is your absolute path you can specify it as the custom checkout directory under Version Control Settings tab.

[image]

Comment: server-side vs agent-side checkout appears to be "all or nothing" - but i want server-side checkout for most of my repos, and agent-side checkout for a certain repo that is to be located at a specific absolute path on agent

Comment: @BaltoStar You can specify additional checkout options in your individual job configuration. If you are using a parameterized VCS Root with something like %GitRemoteURL% and %GitBranch% you can set these per job configuration similar to the checkout rules.